# ElasticSearch replication home/server

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running a local ElasticSearch server from my own home, but would like access to the content from outside. Since I am on a dynamic IP and besides that do not feel comfortable opening up ports to the outside, I would like to rent a VPS somewhere, setup ElasticSearch and let this server be a read only copy of the one I have at home.

As I understand it, this should be possible - however I have been unsuccessful at creating any usable version that lets another server be a read-only version of my home ES-server.

Can anyone point me to a piece of information or create a guide, that would help me to set this up? I am rather known to ES-usage, however my setup-skills are still vague.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it, this should be possible

It might be possible with some workarounds, but it's definitely not built for that:

1. One cluster needs to be in one physical region; mainly because of latency and the stability of the network connection.
2. There are no read-only versions. You could only allow read access to a node (via a reverse proxy or the security plugin), but that's only a workaround.